# Asymptotic value of Meijer G-function

Tags: asymptotics, residue-calculus, hypergeometric-function

I would like to get the Asymptotic Value of the following Meijer G-function when z tends to zero.

I found that I can calculate the residue at the closest pole to the contour from the right since $z \rightarrow o$, which in my case is a 2nd order pole $s= -\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a positive real number

\begin{align}
f(z)=& ~G^{3,1}_{2,3}\left(z\bigg|{-\alpha,1-\alpha\atop 0,-\alpha,-\alpha}\right)%
=
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{\Gamma^2(-\alpha-s)\Gamma(-s)}{1}\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha+s) }{\Gamma(1-\alpha-s)} z^s ds
\end{align}

This leads to having two poles to the right of the contour, simple pole at s=0 and 2nd order pole at $s= -\alpha$, then the closest pole is $s= -\alpha$. So, to calculate the residue at the 2nd order pole, I tried the following:
\begin{align}
\bar{f}(z)=& \operatorname*{Res}_{s=-\alpha}\left(\frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(s+1-\alpha)\Gamma(1-s)}{s}z^{-s}\right)\\%
=& \frac{1}{(2-1)!} \lim_{s\rightarrow -\alpha} \frac{d}{ds} \big[(s+\alpha)^2~\frac{\Gamma^2(-\alpha-s)\Gamma(-s)}{1}\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha+s) }{\Gamma(1-\alpha-s)} z^s\big]
\end{align}

I do not know how to proceed from here. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is $\Gamma^2(-\alpha - s) g(s)$, where $g$ is regular at $-\alpha \not \in \mathbb Z$. Then
$$-\operatorname*{Res}_{s = -\alpha} \Gamma^2(-\alpha - s) g(s) =
-\operatorname*{Res}_{s = -\alpha}
 \frac {\pi^2 g(s)} {\Gamma^2(1 + \alpha + s)} \, \csc^2 \pi (\alpha + s) = \\
-\frac d {ds} \frac {g(s)} {\Gamma^2(1 + \alpha + s)}
 \bigg\rvert_{s = -\alpha} =
-\Gamma(\alpha) z^{-\alpha} (\ln z - \psi(\alpha)).$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I did not get it, but it seems that you used the Gamma reflection formula $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \pi \csc(\pi z)$.

Comment: How to move from the first line to the next line?

Comment: Suppose the expansion is around $s = 0$ and $g$ is regular. Then
$$g(s) \csc^2 s = (g(0) + g'(0) s + O(s^2)) (s^{-2} + O(1)).$$

Comment: Thank you Maxim,  that is helpfull