# The asymptotic behaviour of the Meijer G function

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions

I need to investigate the asymptotic behaviour of the following Meijer G function at the origin
\begin{equation}
G_{1,2}^{2,0}(x) \left(\begin{matrix} 1-a\\
                                        0, 0
                          \end{matrix} \bigg| z \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_{L}\frac{\Gamma^2(-s)}{\Gamma(1-a-s)}z^sds, 
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
where $a>1$ and is noninteger, $L$ is a loop beginning and ending at $+\infty$, encircling all poles of $\Gamma(−s)$ that are $k=0,1,...$

According to the residue theorem
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\limits_{L}\frac{\Gamma^2(-s)}{\Gamma(1-a-s)}z^sds = \sum_{k=0}^\infty Res\left(\frac{\Gamma^2(-s)}{\Gamma(1-a-s)}z^s, k\right),$$ where the integrand has double poles for all $k=0,1,2...$ Thus,

$$Res\left(\frac{\Gamma^2(-s)}{\Gamma(1-a-s)}z^s, k\right) = \lim_{s\to k}\frac{d}{dz}\left[ (s-k)^2\frac{\Gamma^2(-s)}{\Gamma(1-a-s)}z^s\right]$$ $$= \frac{z^k\ln z + \Phi(1-a-k)z^k + c_k\gamma z^k}{(k!)^2\Gamma(1-a-k)},$$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is a polygamma function, and $\gamma$ is  the Euler–Mascheroni constant, and $c_k$ are some constants depending on $k$. The correctness of my calculations can be checked in [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Residue%5B%CE%93%28-s%29%5E2%2F%CE%93%281-a-s%29*z%5Es%2C%7Bs%2C0%7D%5D). Thus, from the definition of Meijer G and above calculations it follows that

$$
G_{1,2}^{2,0}(x) \left(\begin{matrix} 1-a\\
                                        0, 0
                          \end{matrix} \bigg| z \right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k\ln z + \Phi(1-a-k)z^k + c_k\gamma z^k}{(k!)^2\Gamma(1-a-k)}$$

$$= \ln z \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k!)^2\Gamma(1-a-k)} + R(a,z) = \frac{\ln z \; {}_{1}F_{1}(a,1,-z)}{\Gamma(1-a)} +  R(a,z),$$ where $R(a,z)\to const$ as $z\to 0.$ Thus,

$$G_{1,2}^{2,0}(x) \left(\begin{matrix} 1-a\\
                                        0, 0
                          \end{matrix} \bigg| z \right) \sim \frac{\ln z \; {}_{1}F_{1}(a,1,-z)}{\Gamma(1-a)}$$ as $z\to 0.$

However, when I run the following code in MatLab $2020$b, I get the following plot showing that my calculations are not correct.

```
syms a;

a = 2.5;

x = 0.01:0.01:0.1;

plot(x, meijerG([],[1-a], [0,0], [],x)./(log(x).*hypergeom(a,1,-x)./gamma(1-a)))
```

$\mathrm{MeilerG}/(\ln z * \mathrm{hypergeom}(a,1,-z))$:
[image: 2]

I have reviewed other topics related to this problem [Guidance on reducing this Meijer-G function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835925/guidance-on-reducing-this-meijer-g-function), [Asymptotic value of Meijer G-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310661/asymptotic-value-of-meijer-g-function) and it looks like my approach to this integral should be correct. Please, let me know if I missed something in my calculations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you for considering my question. Could you please give me more information about WA or MMa? I googled about it but did not find any information.

Comment: The function is 
$$meijerG([],[1-a],[0,0],[],z),$$ where a>1 and is noninteger. 
To calculate residuals, I used the following command 
$$Residue[gamma(-s)^2/gamma(1-a-s)*z^s,{s,k}].$$ After applying residue theorem, I got that the asymptotic behaviour of meijerG([],[1-a],[0,0],[],z) at the origin is $$log(z)*hypergeom(a,1,-z).$$

Comment: Sorry, that MeijerG was from MatLab. In Wolfram Alpha, it is 
$$MeijerG[\{\{\}, \{-a\}\}, \{\{0, 0\}, \{\}\}, z]$$

Comment: The only issue is that $L$ has to encircle the poles of $\Gamma(-s)$ in the negative direction, so the integral is equal to minus the sum of the residues. Then $G = -\ln(x)/\Gamma(1 - a) + C + O(|x \ln x|)$, which means $G/(-\ln(x)/\Gamma(1 - a))$ converges to $1$ only logarithmically.

Comment: Do [these special cases](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/04/04/) help simplify? Using the second formula from the top gets you [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28-z%29+U%281-a%2C+1%2C+z%29)

Comment: Thank you, Maxim. I see now that my calculations were correct, but I forgot that minus. You are right, the rate of convergence is very slow, which is why I did not see it on the plot above. Thank you, Maxim.

Comment: Hi Tyma Gaidash, thank you. I can see that it gives the same result. 
I have a question about the U function. This function is defined as 
$$ U(a,b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a+1-b)} {}_{1}F_{1}(a,b,z) + \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a)}z^{1-b} {}_{1}F_{1}(a+1-b,2-b,z).$$ However, it doesn't work for $b=1.$ I suspect that the following method of analytic continuation is used to define $U(a,1,z)$:
$$U(a,1,z) = \lim_{b\to 1} U(a,b,z).$$ 
In Lebedev: Special functions and their applications, they use the same method to define ${}_{2}F_{1}(a,b,z)$ for $a+b-c=n,$ where $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding as series around $z=0$
$$f(z)=G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(z\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1-a \\
 0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ $$f(z)=\frac{-\psi ^{(0)}(1-a)-\log (z)-2 \gamma }{\Gamma (1-a)}+\frac{ (-\psi
   ^{(0)}(-a)-\log (z)-2 \gamma +2)}{\Gamma (-a)}z+O\left(z^2\right)$$

$$g(z)=\frac{\log (z) \, _1F_1(a;1;-z)}{\Gamma (1-a)}$$
$$g(z)=\frac{\log (z)}{\Gamma (1-a)}-\frac{\log (z)}{\Gamma (-a)}z+O\left(z^2\right)$$

$$f(z)\color{red}{\mathbf{+}}g(z)=\frac{\psi ^{(0)}(1-a)+2 \gamma }{\Gamma (1-a)}-\frac{\psi ^{(0)}(-a)+2 \gamma -2}{\Gamma (-a)}z+O\left(z^2\right)$$